# What is the difference between a socket and a port connection in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sockets, tcp

when I am using 'localhost' as the host for MySQL database, sequel pro alert me that I will be using socket. On the other hand, if I use '127.0.0.1', i would be using the ip address and port 3306 to reach the server.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Unix socket is a data communications endpoint that is similar to an [network socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket), but does not use a network protocol for communication. These are used in POSIX operating systems for inter-process communication. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket))

The "localhost -> socket" rule appears to be hardcoded in the MySQL client library, according to a forum post by a MySQL developer. ([Source](http://www.mombu.com/programming/php/t-replace-localhost-unix-socket-connection-by-localhost-tcpip-connection-1367681.html))

Comment: Yeah, it's quicker to transfer over a socket than a TCP port because it avoids the overhead of the network stack.  I think PostgreSQL does the same thing.

Comment: Careful with the terminology - a TCP port is part of a socket. (In fact, a port isn't a 'thing' at all, just a number associated with a socket.) It just happens to be a different type of socket...